# What argument can I use inside the **noSuchMethod()** method in flutter to handle null snapshot data?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I have an **AsyncSnapshot** that stores data from a Future method. Just recently I discovered that I have to handle an error when the data returned is null.

What argument is missing inside the **noSuchMethod()** method in the following code snippet?

```
      else if (snapshot.noSuchMethod(..missingArg..)){
          // Do something
      }
```

Apparently **noSuchMethod()** take in a parameter type of Class **Invocation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything with `noSuchMethod()`.

You can check if the snapshot doesn't have the data simply by

```
if(!snapshot.hasData) {
  // show loading indicator
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to call `noSuchMethod` at all. It is way more readable and understandable to check if snapshot is null directly, so consider changing your snippet to:

```dart
      else if (snapshot == null){
          // Do something
      }
```